# How can I divide a variable multiple times in a function with Javascipt?

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

I have an issue with trying to create a function that calculates the remaining quantity of a material depending on its half-life.

```
function halfLife(quantity, halfLifeTime, timeElapsed) {
    let decay = (timeElapsed / halfLifeTime);
    let remainingQuantity;

    if (decay >= 1 && decay % 1 === 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < decay; i++) {
            remainingQuantity = quantity / 2;
        }
        return remainingQuantity;
    } else if (decay < 1) {
        let partialDecay = .5 / halfLifeTime;
        return remainingQuantity = quantity - partialDecay;
    }
}

let actual = halfLife(1, 4, 1);
let expected = .875;

if (actual === expected) {
    console.log("Test PASSED!");
} else {
    console.error("Test FAILED.");
    console.group("Result:");
    console.log("  actual:", actual);
    console.log("expected:", expected);
    console.groupEnd();
}

actual = halfLife(2, 2, 4);
expected = 1 / 2;

if (actual === expected) {
    console.log("Test PASSED!");
} else {
    console.error("Test FAILED. Keep trying!");
    console.group("Result:");
    console.log("  actual:", actual);
    console.log("expected:", expected);
    console.groupEnd();
}
```

If an input has to be divided more than once, the first 'if' statement will only divide an input once and return it. The first test I made works correctly, but the second is the issue.  Sorry if something isn't clear, I'm still learning!

Answer (score 2):

In your loop you have

```
for (let i = 0; i < decay; i++) {
  remainingQuantity = quantity / 2;
}
```

But as `quantity` never changes in the loop, the result of that division is always the same. Ie, you are always dividing the original `quantity` value by 2.

You probably want something like

```
let remainingQuantity = quantity;
for (let i = 0; i < decay; i++) {
  remainingQuantity = remainingQuantity / 2; 
  
  // or the short form of the above 
  // remainingQuantity /= 2;
}
```

Note that `a /= 2` is the short form of `a = a / 2`. So use only *one*  of the two statements in the loop. Whichever you like better.

**EDIT**

Besides the issues with programming, the way you calculate the partial decay seems a bit off too.

First of all, it seems strange that for a quarter of the halflife time the decay is exactly 1/8. That doesn't fit the exponential nature of radioactive decay. The expected value would be about `0.841`

Furthermore it seems the amount of the partial decay isn't related to the initial quantity at all. So if you call `halfLife(10, 4, 1)` the result will be `9.875`. For `halfLife(100, 4, 1)` it will be `99.875`, and so on and so forth. These results are obviously wrong ...